# Flutter using http request to register

Tags: android, ios, mobile, dart, flutter

I'm developing an app using flutter and I'm trying to implement a registration process for new users.

Basically, I implemented a TextFormField that sends a request to the server for each field.

I'm requiring the user for a phone number, then smsing them a pin number and they have to use it to register.

For that, I want to use the TextFormField validate method and send the http request from there, so I can update the TextFormField error message according to the reply from the server.
Alas, the http API provided by dart is asynchronous I am not quite sure how to implement it properly.

I'm aware of the flutter widget for streams and async functions but it seems to be used for dynamic widgets while I want to trigger the call when the user click a button.

I can also think of work arounds, like updating a global variable and using 'hackish' call backs from the async function to test for when the function is done.

Here is the code I'm using right now, I'd love some feedback or a direction I should go for:

```
validator: (value){
    if(value.length != 6){
      return 'This is not a proper otp';
    }
    http.post('$host/reg', body: '{ "id" : "${details['phone']}", "otp" : "$value" }', headers: { "Content-Type" : "application/json"}).then((reply){
        if(!json.decode(reply.body)['success']) {
            return 'Incorrect verification code';
        }}
```

Right now, the validation will work regardless, and I can't really use 'await' for that matter since the function have to be async for that to work, which validator method doesn't allow.

Comment: In general, we will validate only the `count` or `pattern`(like only numbers) in the validator. `Network call validations` are better to move to submit button action. Does that make sense?

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian, It does, thank you very much. I suppose I'll have to role my own error message prompt for the server reply then? I saw that as the easiest solution, making sure that is the way to go however, thank you in advance.

Comment: I agree with you